# React Native display message at certain time when app is disabled

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, alarm

How is it possible to have React Native trigger some kind of message on the device at a certain time, even if the app is currently not selected or closed down altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply use a push notification. This is something you will need to setup server side but it sounds like you have a good use case. You will need to setup permissions etc for this.

Maybe also a good use case for local notifications take a look at [React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#schedulelocalnotification)

Comment: Is this also how you'd trigger an alarm clock going off? What if you disallow push notifications, then you won't hear the alarm?

Comment: I don't think a server would be required, a local notification would do the trick with this use case..

Answer (score 0):

A small completion to @JamesWatling's answer. You'll need at least:

- AppState (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html#content) to post the timestamp to server, when app is moved to background
- Push Notifications (e.g. https://onesignal.com/ or for iOS: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content) to send a notification after certain amount of time

Comment: I don't think a server would be required, a local notification would do the trick with this use case..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html) part of the react native documentation and focus on *local* notifications. You don't need a server or anything to schedule a notification at a given time, a local notification is scheduled without a server interfering.

I do believe your app is going to need to have permissions for push notifications though (so the app is allowed to display a message on a homescreen for instance)